# Print C++ array in Objective-C "NSLog"

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays

I'm trying to output and C++ Array (`int inverse[3]`) using `NSLog`, but If I try this way:

```
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", inverse]);
```

It just dont work, But if I try like this:

```
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", inverse[0]]);
```

I get the right output.
My objective is to get the whole array outputed.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need need to convert for string format conversion. You can print like these -

```
for ( int i=0; i<3; ++i )
    NSLog(@"%i", inverse[i]);
```

Comment: I want to print the whole array, and not just one int.

Comment: Anh.. THought it'll be an easier way to output this. Hate filling my code with 'unecessary' "fors" and "whiles". Thanks anyway :D

Comment: @markus: a function can't know the size of the array passed to it, so the syntax you want is just not possible in c++. you can write a function of your own that takes array and size, but nothing that can only take array.

Answer (score 3):

Use a for loop to print all the values.

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%i", inverse[i]);
}
```

or:

```
NSLog(@"%i, %i, %i", inverse[0], inverse[1], inverse[2]);
```